# Print empty string in place of null datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, kendo-ui, nullable

I have in property in model like,

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> dateinvoice { get; set; }
```

i bind it to my view, Now when it is null it is printing null in view, how can i print empty string there.

I can do this with simple check in cshtml, but unfortunatly i am using KendoUI.

```
  columns.Bound(p => p.dateinvoice).ClientTemplate(
                                            "<span style='color:red;'>" +
                                                "#= kendo.toString(dateinvoice,'MM/dd/yy') #" + "</span>"
                                        ).Width(100).Title("<span>Date of<br/>Invoice</span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend wrapping the property in a string property that contains the date formatting and the fallback on empty string. I like that better than string formatting in the view.

Comment: ah that may be not possible in my case, as i need that property to map with my stored procedure function in EF.

Comment: Ok. One way is to create a view model object on top of your model object and bind that. It's often good to abstract the EF model in order to avoid logic in the views

Answer (score 0):

ok here what i did. a trick or a simple way.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.dateinvoice).ClientTemplate(
"<span style='color:red;'>" + "#= kendo.toString(
```

> **dateinvoice == null ? ' ' : dateinvoice,'MM/dd/yy'**

```
) #" + "</span>".Width(100).Title("<span>Date of<br/>Invoice</span>");
```